# 64-bit and 32-bit Linux distros

Tags: linux

Are all 64-bit installers of Linux distros have command line installation setups? If so, why is this the case? If not, then why are most 64-bit Linux distros have command-line installation setups? Are there existing 64-bit installations that are GUI?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you got this impression. All of the major modern distributions include GUI-mode installation for both 64-bit and 32-bit versions.

Here's the 64-bit DVD ISO for Fedora 14, currently the latest release:

http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/14/Fedora/x86_64/iso/Fedora-14-x86_64-DVD.iso

And here's the same for Ubuntu 10.10, also currently the latest:

http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/DVDs/ubuntu/10.10/release/ubuntu-10.10-dvd-amd64.iso

Comment: odd, cuz I grabbed a 64-bit ISO of Ubuntu 10.10 and it's in command line...hm...

Comment: See screenshots of it being installed in GUI mode: http://www.theosquest.com/2010/10/10/ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat-installed-to-virtualbox/ Maybe you can explain what you're doing in more depth?

Answer (score 0):

I know for a fact that SLES 11 has a GUI installer, and that comes in 64-bit flavors. I see that RHEL 6 also has a GUI installer ([link](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/red-hat-6-installation-guide-rhel-6-install-screenshots/)).

Answer (score 0):

All of the RHEL-based installations (including RedHat linux itself, and derivatives such as CentOS) have GUI installers for both 64 bit and 32 bit systems.  In general, I believe most major distributions use effectively the same installers for both architectures.